# bash text parsing with multiple conditions nested

Tags: bash, parsing, text, nested, multiple-conditions

I have the following code that checks for lines over 10 words and splits them where the first comma character appears. It reiterates the process so all newly split lines with over 10 words and commas are also split (in the end there are no lines with over 10 words and commas).

How do I edit this code to do the following: after all the comma splitting is done(what the current code already does), the resulting lines are checked if they have over 10 words and split where the first "and " (with space) appears?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input=input.txt
temp=$(mktemp ${input}.XXXX)
trap "rm -f $temp" 0

while awk '
  BEGIN { retval=1 }
  NF >= 10 && /, / {
    sub(/, /, ","ORS)
    retval=0
  }
  1
  END { exit retval }
' "$input" > "$temp"; do
  mv -v $temp $input
done
```

Input sample:

```
Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4, Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9

Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4, Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10 Word11

Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4, Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10, Word11 Word12 Word13 Word14 Word15 Word16 

Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4, Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10 Word11 and Word12 Word13 Word14 Word15 

Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4 and Word5
```

Desired output:

```
Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4, Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9

Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4, 
Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10 Word11

Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4,
 Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10,
 Word11 Word12 Word13 Word14 Word15 Word16 

Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4, 
Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10 Word11 and
 Word12 Word13 Word14 Word15 

Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4 and Word5
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please show me input data and expected output.

Comment: Yuji, I edited to show sample of input and output data. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
awk '{
    while (split($0, a, "( +and +)|( +)") > 10 && match($0, "( +and +)|,")) {
        if (match($0, "[^,]+,")) {
            # puts a newline after the 1st comma
            print substr($0, 1, RLENGTH)
            $0 = substr($0, RLENGTH + 1)
        } else {
            # puts a newline before the 1st substring " and "
            n = split($0, a, " +and +")
            if (a[1] == "") {               # $0 starts with " and "
                a[1] = " and " a[2]
                for (i = 2; i < n; i++) {
                    a[i] = a[i+1]
                }
                n--
            }
            print a[1]
            $0 = " and " a[2]
            for (i = 3; i <= n; i++) {      # there are two ore more " and "
                $0 = $0 " and " a[i]
            }
        }
    }
    print
}' input.txt
```

Output for the given input:

```
Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4, Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9

Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4,
 Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10 Word11

Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4,
 Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10,
 Word11 Word12 Word13 Word14 Word15 Word16

Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4,
 Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10 Word11
 and Word12 Word13 Word14 Word15

Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4 and Word5
```

**[Explanations]**

- It iterates on the same record while the pattern space contains
  more than 10 fields (excluding the word "and") && the pattern space
  includes the line separator(s) in order to enable succesive splitting.
- If the pattern space contains a comma, then print the left hand
  and update the pattern space with the right hand.
- If the pattern space contains the word " and ", the processing is a bit
  difficult because the word remains in the updated pattern space.
  My approach may not be elegant in a sense but it works even if a record
  contains multiple (two or more) " and "s.

**[EDIT]**

If you want to include the word `and` as a part of the word count, please replace the 2nd line:

```
while (split($0, a, "( +and +)|( +)") > 10 && match($0, "( +and +)|,")) {
```

with:

```
while (NF > 10 && match($0, "( +and +)|,")) {
```

In addition, if you allow the word `and` to follow the
original line: the script will be a bit simplified as:

```
awk '{
    while (NF > 10 && match($0, "( +and +)|,")) {
        if (match($0, "[^,]+,")) {
            # puts a newline after the 1st comma
            print substr($0, 1, RLENGTH)
            $0 = substr($0, RLENGTH + 1)
        } else {
            # puts a newline after the 1st substring " and "
            n = split($0, a, " +and +")
            print a[1] " and"
            $0 = " " a[2]
            for (i = 3; i <= n; i++) {      # there are two ore more " and "
                $0 = $0 " and " a[i]
            }
        }
    }
    print
}' input.txt
```

Moreover, if `Perl` is your option, you can say:

```
perl -ne '{
    while (split > 10 && /( +and +)|,/) {
        if (/^.*?(, *| +and +)/) {
            print $&, "\n";
            $_ = " $'\''";
        }
    }
    print
}' input.txt
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the explanation. Slight misunderstanding regarding the word "and "; I actually wanted it to also be counted as part of the word count.  Further,  until you mentioned it, I didn't realize that having the and in the new line causes problems since and is also part of the search criteria. I could have lived with having "and" also in the original line. UV

Comment: @HenryM Thank you for testing my answer. I've updated the script according to your comment. BR.

Comment: yes that's great. I'll analyze it to better understand how you approached the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this your expected answer?

```
echo "Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4, Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10, Word11 Word12 Word13 Word14 Word15 Word16 Word17 Word18 Word19 Word20 Word21 and Word22 Word23 Word24." | grep -oE '[a-zA-Z0-9,.]+' | awk '
BEGIN {
    cnt = 0
}
{
    str = str " " $0
    if ($0 ~ /,$/){
        print str
        cnt = 0
        str = ""
    }
    else if (cnt < 10){
        cnt++
    }
    else {
        print str
        cnt = 0
        str = ""
    }
} END {
    print str
}' | sed 's/^ *//'
```

```
Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4,
Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10,
Word11 Word12 Word13 Word14 Word15 Word16 Word17 Word18 Word19 Word20 Word21
and Word22 Word23 Word24.
```

Comment: No because this splits commas even for sentences with less than 10 words. Only if a line has more than 10 words, I want it to be split by comma, then if the remaining sentence is still over 10 words I want it to be split by the words "and".

Comment: Please look at your "Desired output".